# Dúvida ao unir arquivos txt

Tags: cmd

Procurando na internet como unir arquivos txt, encontrei o código de linha de comando CMD abaixo:

`for %f in (*.txt) do "%f" >> união.txt`

A lógica é fazer um loop, pegar todos os arquivos txt e criar um novo arquivo 'união.txt' com todos eles juntos.

O mesmo não funciona, ele abre todos os arquivos e cria o novo, mas o novo fica em branco.

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu conseguir resolver desta forma:

`for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> união.txt`

O código diz o seguinte:

`for %f in (*txt)` //faz um loop em todos os arquivos .txt

`do type` //**o comando type estava faltando** ele é o comando escrever

`"%f" >> união.txt` //escreve o conteúdo dos arquivos dentro do arquivo união.txt

Comment: Poderia discorrer mais sobre sua resposta? Seria interessante se pudesse dar mais detalhes do que você mudou, e como isso se diferencia do código da pergunta.

Comment: @Stormwind dei uma explicada no comando. Abraço

Answer (score 2):

Use cópia `/B`inária:

```bat
copy /B *.txt unir.txt
```

Answer (score -3):

O comando cat pode ser uma boa opção também:

```
cat *.log > unir.txt
```